# How to send files from server to another server, server is not with 22 port

Tags: php, sftp

I want to trasnfer my files on server to another server with port no 220 and SFTP protocol. When I execute following code, my connection to that sever is getting established with correct username and password, but files are not getting transfered on destination.

My local server is Azure and destination is windows server. Kindly suggest.

This is my code I am trying with:

```
<?php
   $localFile='/filepath/file1.txt';
   $remoteFile='/remote_server_files/file1.txt';

   $host = "hostname";
   $port = 220;//Here that server is open with 220 port
   $user = "username";
   $pass = "password";

   echo "<pre>result of connection----".$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
   ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pass);
   $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

   $stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$remoteFile", 'w');
   $file = file_get_contents($localFile);
   echo "<br>result of file write----".fwrite($stream, $file);
   fclose($stream);
?>
```

Comment: Please provide some more details. What is the `var_dump()` of `$stream` and `fwrite()`?

Comment: Its bool(false) for $stream

Comment: That means, `fopen()` failed to open given file.

Comment: Shall I need to append relative or absolute path to mentioned file? given in code file is inside DOCUMENT_ROOT and there is a folder from where I am getting files to transfer. Please clear this one

Comment: Your one clue worked well!!! thanks millions times :)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: It's always a nice gesture to upvote valuable comments or answers showing some appreciation to those who took their free time to help solve an issue. 